# ivector extraction from audio

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-bob

Good afternoon,

I am looking at extracting ivectors from audio clips. Is python-bob the best library to use? Having difficulty finding any useful documentation so would appreciate any points in the right direction.

thanks

Comment: Yes, you would use bob.bio.spear and bob.learn.em to train and extract ivectors. Could you please explain more on what you have tried so far?

Comment: bob.bio.spear was removed from bob 9 release (but it will be come back by the end of summer) so you want to install bob 8 and read its docs at https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/install.html#installing-older-versions-of-bob

Comment: Thanks for the response, ive been looking through all the old google hangout chats. I'm relatively new to python but have been given this task so finding it somewhat challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking a very broad question, I can only give you a broad answer.

To extract ivectors, you need to train the background model first. [bob.bio.spear](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/bob/bob.bio.spear/doc/index.html) is the main library that you can use to do this.
[bob.db.voxforge](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/bob/bob.db.voxforge/doc/index.html) can be used as a toy database example to get you started.
bob.bio.spear was removed from Bob 9 release (it's being revived for the next release of Bob) so you have to install bob 8 and read [bob 8 documentation](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0)

So here is how to install bob 8 relevant packages:

```sh
$ conda create --name bob-8 --override-channels \
  -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda -c defaults \
  -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/label/archive \
python=3 bob=8 bob.bio.spear bob.db.voxforge gridtk bob.bio.gmm
$ conda activate bob-8
$ conda config --env --add channels defaults
$ conda config --env --add channels https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/label/archive
$ conda config --env --add channels https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda
$ # conda install more packages if you need them. like:
$ # conda install bob.db.iris
```

Here are some useful links that can help you get started:

- https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/tutorial.html
- https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/bob/bob.bio.base/doc/index.html
- https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/bob/bob.bio.spear/doc/index.html
- https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/bob/bob.db.voxforge/doc/index.html

If you want to look at the code at Gitlab, you have to browse the code in the tag which is associated with Bob 8 release:
https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob/-/blob/v8.0.0/requirements.txt

For example, to browse bob.bio.base code, look at https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.bio.base/-/tree/v4.1.1

For a minimal example, to train and test and i-vector system on the voxforge database, run:

```sh
$ download_and_untar_voxforge.py --address ~/databases/voxforge
$ echo "[YOUR_VOXFORGE_DIRECTORY]=$HOME/databases/voxforge" > ~/.bob_bio_databases.txt
$ verify.py -vvv -d voxforge -p energy-2gauss -e mfcc-60 -a ivec-plda-voxforge -s ivec-plda --groups {dev,eval} --parallel 4
```

then, if you want to test on your own data, you can create a filelist database interface following https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/v8.0.0/bob/bob.bio.base/doc/filelist-guide.html

Comment: wowzer thank you very much for all your help! very much appreciated.